# How to find the largest number of decimal places in a file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, decimal

I want to find the biggest decimal count inside a file

```
 0   data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
 1
 2  dec = abs(decimal.Decimal('20.122').as_tuple().exponent)
 3  print(dec)
```

so here the first line reads the file, the third line counts the decimals and the 4th prints it, now it prints 3 ('20.122' has 3 decimals)
so now i want to search the data.csv  and find the number with most decimals (e.g 2.0345) and then count the decimals using the third line

[Is there a way to find the largest number of decimal places in an Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849428/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-largest-number-of-decimal-places-in-an-excel)

this is exactly what i want, but its in excel

I'm using pandas here, and there is only one column called "data"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your columns of interest contains `strings` as you demonstrate in your example, you can use the `.apply()` function.

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame([['4.5'], ['4.61'], ['4.73']], columns=['decimal'])
```

**First** create a function to count decimals, as you already did

```
def count_decimals(input_string):
    return abs(decimal.Decimal(input_string).as_tuple().exponent)
```

**Then** apply this function for each column that you want to count the decimals of (and assign this result to a new column)

```
df.assign(decimal_count=lambda x: x['decimal'].apply(count_decimals))
```

**Result**

```
decimal     decimal_count
0   4.5     1
1   4.61    2
2   4.73    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this
The maxDecimalPlaces variable will be updated with the highest decimal places of the value present in the data.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
maxDecimalPlaces = 0

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    # considering you want to evaluate on a column say col_name
    decimalPlaces = abs(decimal.Decimal(row["col_name"]).as_tuple().exponent)
    
    if decimalPlaces > maxDecimalPlaces:
      maxDecimalPlaces = decimalPlaces
```

Assuming pd is pandas and keeping the same method for getting decimal places as provided in the question.

If you want to run on multiple columns add another loop on colnames.